# What is the probability that a sample value from a Binomial distributions is smaller than a sample value from another?

Tags: probability, binomial-distribution

Let $X \sim \mathrm{Binomial} (n, p_1)$ and let $Y \sim \mathrm{Binomial} (n, p_2)$ with $n, p_1$ and $p_2$ known and $p_1 < p_2$.

What is the probability that a sample value $x$ drawn from $X$ is smaller than a sample value $y$ drawn from $Y$?  That is, what is $P(X<Y)$?

Comment: Yes; that a sample drawn from X is smaller than another sample drawn from Y.

Comment: The trick here is to use the [law of total probability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability); if you know that $Y=y$, then you can calculate $P(X<y)$, by summing $X$'s probability mass function, $P(X=x) = \binom{n}{x} p_{1}^{x} (1-p_1)^{n-x}$, over $x=0,...,y$. Then you just take the expected value of that quantity, with respect to $Y$. Btw, the result is probably not going to look pretty :)

Comment: And if $Y=y$ can take any value, one would multiply $P(Y=y)$ with $P(X<y)$.  Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, and sum over the whole domain $y=0,1,...,n$. This is what I meant by taking the expected value with respect to $Y$

Comment: Thank you.  So long as the results match the data, pretty is not a problem :)

Comment: $P(X<Y)$ is equivalent to $P(X-Y<0)$; in turn, that's $P(X+(-Y)<0)$ which equals $P(X+(n-Y)<n)$, and $(n-Y)\sim \rm{Bin}(n,1-p_2)$; each can be useful. If $n$ is not really large you can do the last by numerical convolution; I've done some decent-sized ones in R on negative binomials in the past; binomials are even better suited to it. If $n$ is not small and the $p$'s are not really close to the boundaries (the two are linked), you can approximate this probability pretty well using normal distributions (I'd suggest using a continuity correction on the difference $X-Y$ and comparing to 0).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although an explicit formula might be tricky, it's quite easy to evaluate numerically. The key is to realize the $X$ and $Y$ are independent.

Start by pretending you know $Y=y$.  You know that if $X \sim \mathcal{B}(n_1,p_1)$ then:
$$P[X=x] = \binom{n_1}{x}p_1^x(1-p_1)^{n_1-x}$$

From there you can easily find:
$$P[X \le y] = \sum_{x=0}^{y} \binom{n_1}{x}p_1^x(1-p_1)^{n_1-x}$$

Because $X$ and $Y$ are independent, we know:
$$P[X<Y] = \sum_{y=0}^{n_2}P[X<y] * P[Y=y]$$
$$= \sum_{y=0}^{n_2}\left(\sum_{x=0}^{y} \binom{n_1}{x}p_1^x(1-p_1)^{n_1-x}\right)\binom{n_2}{y}p_2^y(1-p_2)^{n_2-y}$$